# TFS Security: Where is the "Create a new Publisher" permission?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm trying to publish my web extension to an on-premises TFS 2017U3:

`tfx extension publish --service-url "http://fqdn:8080/tfs"`

It tells me the account doesn't have permission to "Create a new publisher":

> Checking if this extension is already published It isn't, create a new
>   extension. error: Received response 403 (Forbidden). Check that you
>   have access to this res ource. Message from server: Failed Request:
>   Forbidden(403) - Access Denied: (account name) needs the following
>   permission(s) on the resource  to perform this  action: Create a new
>   publisher

I've checked the following links, but none of them mention any "Create a new publisher" permission:

- [About permissions and groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/about-permissions?view=vsts#permission-settings)
- [Grant permissions to manage
  extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/marketplace/how-to/grant-permissions?toc=/vsts/security/toc.json&bc=/vsts/security/breadcrumb/toc.json&view=vsts)
- [Set build and release permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/set-permissions?toc=/vsts/security/toc.json&bc=/vsts/security/breadcrumb/toc.json&view=vsts)
- [Add administrators, set permissions at the project-level or project collection-level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/set-project-collection-level-permissions?view=vsts)
- [Permissions lookup guide for VSTS & TFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/permissions-lookup-guide?view=vsts)
- [Google search tfs "create a new publisher" permission](https://www.google.ca/search?q=tfs%20%22create%20a%20new%20publisher%22%20permission&rlz=1C1GGRV_enCA768CA768&oq=tfs%20%22create%20a%20new%20publisher%22%20permission&aqs=chrome..69i57.4703j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Where can I find the "Create a new publisher" permission?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this:

**1 - At the server level, create a group, for example, "TFS Extension Publishers":**

tfssecurity /gcg "TFS Extension Publishers" "publishers who can manage extensions for the server" /server:ServerURL

**2 - Grant access to the "TFS Extension Publishers" group to manage extensions:**

tfssecurity /a+ Publisher "//" CreatePublisher n:"[TEAM FOUNDATION]\TFS Extension Publishers" allow /server:ServerURL

tfssecurity /a+ Publisher "//" PublishExtension n:"[TEAM FOUNDATION]\TFS Extension Publishers" allow /server:ServerURL

tfssecurity /a+ Publisher "//" UpdateExtension n:"[TEAM FOUNDATION]\TFS Extension Publishers" allow /server:ServerURL

tfssecurity /a+ Publisher "//" DeleteExtension n:"[TEAM FOUNDATION]\TFS Extension Publishers" allow /server:ServerURL

**3 - Add existing users and groups to the "TFS Extension Publishers" group.**

tfssecurity /g+ "[TEAM FOUNDATION]\TFS Extension Publishers" n:User /server:ServerURL

Full reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/vsts/marketplace/how-to/grant-permissions?toc=/vsts/security/toc.json&bc=/vsts/security/breadcrumb/toc.json&view=tfs-2017

Comment: FYI this worked for our issue updating extensions as well:  "Access Denied: LastName, FirstName needs the following permission(s) on the resource /Collection/ResourceName to perform this action: Make changes to, share, or view certificate of an existing extension"